# prevent angular schema form's destroyStrategy from removing values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-schema-form

I upgraded my Angular app from version 0.8.2 to 0.8.3 of [Angular Schema Form](http://schemaform.io/) (ASF) and this introduced a whopping great bug.

The forms in this app are multi-page forms and you move from one page to the next using prev/next buttons. A `condition` is used to ensure that only the relevant fields are shown on each page of the form.

The form (model) data is stored in Firebase, but after upgrading to ASF 0.8.3, all the form data is deleted when you move to the next/previous page.

I had a look at the [0.8.3 release notes](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/releases/tag/0.8.3) and I guess this is the reason for the change in behaviour

> "destroyStrategy" support, thanks @jbsaff! This means that condition can now remove values from the model when their fields are hidden

Is there some way that I can disable this such that the data is *not* deleted when fields are hidden (when using version 0.8.3 or later)?

Comment: wouldn't this be a question for the plugin developers?

Comment: @Claies it's a question for anyone who can answer it (including the plugin developers)

Comment: have you asked the developers about the problem, though? you **directly** quote the change they made in their release notes, but you ask here like they wouldn't give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent Angular from deleting the data when a field is hidden, set the global option `destroyStrategy: 'retain'`, e.g.

```
<form sf-schema="schema" 
      sf-form="form" 
      sf-model="fireBaseModel"            
      sf-options="{destroyStrategy: 'retain'}"
      name="current_form"></form>
```